# Remove button not working programatically android

Tags: android, button

So I have a button programmatically that adds edittext, spinner and a remove button when pressed, what I want to do is to remove the edittext, spinner and button when I click the remove button. My code is not working and I can't see the log return. Can someone tell me what should I put on the On Click event base on my codes?

```
public LinearLayout createFields(final int id){
    LinearLayout llLayout = new LinearLayout(Customer.this);
    llLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    TableRow.LayoutParams spinParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, 50, 1f);
    spinParams.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 0);

    TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, 50, 0.5f);
    params.setMargins(5, 5, 0, 0);

    final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(Customer.this);
    spinner.setLayoutParams(spinParams);
    spinner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundedittext);
    spinner.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    final EditText etQty = new EditText(Customer.this);     
    etQty.setLayoutParams(params);
    etQty.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundedittext);
    etQty.setHint("Quantity");
    etQty.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    final EditText etPrice = new EditText(Customer.this);       
    etPrice.setLayoutParams(params);
    etPrice.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundedittext);
    etPrice.setHint("Price");
    etPrice.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    final Button btRemove = new Button(Customer.this);      
    btRemove.setLayoutParams(params);
    //btRemove.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundedittext);
    btRemove.setText("Remove");
    btRemove.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);



    ArrayList<String>itemList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor = db.read("SELECT DISTINCT item_name from item_tb");
    itemList.add("Select Item");
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        itemList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("item_name")));
    }   

    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Customer.this,R.layout.spinner_layout, itemList);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setPrompt("Select Item");
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);



    btRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("REMOVE CLICK", "Tapped ");
        }
    });

    etQty.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence c, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

            SampleObj obj = new SampleObj();

            String itemz = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String itemz2 = db.getValue("SELECT itemID from item_tb where item_name = '"+itemz+"'");
            obj.item  = itemz2;
            obj.qty = c.toString();
            obj.price = etPrice.getText().toString();

            list.set(id, obj);

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        }
    });

    etPrice.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence c, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

            SampleObj obj = new SampleObj();

            String itemz = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String itemz2 = db.getValue("SELECT itemID from item_tb where item_name = '"+itemz+"'");
            obj.item  = itemz2;
            obj.qty = etQty.getText().toString();
            obj.price = c.toString();

            list.set(id, obj);

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        }
    });



    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) {

            SampleObj obj = new SampleObj();

            String itemz = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String itemz2 = db.getValue("SELECT itemID from item_tb where item_name = '"+itemz+"'");
            obj.item  = itemz2;
            obj.qty = etQty.getText().toString();
            obj.price = etQty.getText().toString();

            Customer.list.set(id, obj);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
        });


    llLayout.addView(spinner);
    llLayout.addView(etQty);
    llLayout.addView(etPrice);
    llLayout.addView(btRemove);     
    return llLayout;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define your Edittext, spinner and button globally in your code and then on button click setvisibility of your filed.

So do it something like this.

Define this globally in your code.

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(Customer.this);
EditText etQty = new EditText(Customer.this);     
EditText etPrice = new EditText(Customer.this);
```

and then in onclick of remove try this.

```
btRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            System.out.println("Inside Remove button's click event");

            spinner.setVisibility(View.gone);
            etPriceset.Visibility(View.gone);
            etQty.Visibility(View.gone); 
        }
    });
```

Comment: But I still can't see the log. :( I want to make sure that its working before I put codes.

Comment: Check edited answer and try. You will see `Inside Remove button's click event` this message in log, and if you don't see try to clean or restart eclipse.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! It's working perfectly! I checked your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help you. +1 to you as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss `@Override` onClick Event. So add this may you get result.

Try like this

```
 btRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("REMOVE CLICK", "Tapped ");
    }
});
```

Comment: I still can't see the log. :( I want to make sure that its working before I put codes.

Comment: try to remove `final` for btRemove